# Как преобразовать список в python?

Tags: python

надо удалить слово до определенного символа

Есть список [login:pass]
получить на выход [pass]

Comment: Непонятно - это строка такая в списке или что? Приведите в нормальном питоновском виде данные.

Answer (score 3):

```py
users = ['ivan:parol', 'fedya:123456']

passwords = []
for user in users:
    passwords.append(user.split(':')[1])

print(passwords)
```

Comment: `print(*(passwd[passwd.find(':')+1:] for passwd in users))`